Forify On demand vs Forify SSC
What is the difference between Fortify On Demand and Fortify SSC? If Fortify On Demand is just a cloud version of Fortify SSC, why does Jenkins have two different plugins?
I want to perform static code analysis on my source code, but I’m confused about the differences between Fortify On Demand and Fortify SSC.
To trigger a static scan using Fortify SSC, we need the SCA client, and the command should look like this:
Clean:
`sourceanalyzer -b "Build ID" -clean`
Build:
sourceanalyzer -b "Build ID" devenv BuildID.sln /Rebuild Debug /out "C:\SSCLogs\SSCBuild.log"
Scan:
sourceanalyzer -b "Build ID" -scan -format fpr -f BuildID.fpr
Upload to SSC:
fortifyclient.bat -url SSCServerUrl -authtoken XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX uploadFPR -file BuildID.fpr -project "MyProject" -version "MyProject v1.0.0"


In contrast, to trigger a scan using Fortify On Demand, the command would be:
FodUpload.jar -bsi <token> -z <file> {-ac <key> <secret> | -uc <username> <password>} -ep {1|SingleScan|2|Subscription} [-p {1|Standard|2|Express}] [-a {1|Manual|2|Automated}] [-itp] [-os] [-b] [-r] [-purchase] [-n] [-I <minutes>] [-P <proxy_url> <username> <password> <nt_domain> <nt_workstation>] [-h] [-v]


Can you please help me understand why there are two different approaches and what the differences are? Also, why does Jenkins have two separate plugins for these?
